# Multi select parameter default set by previous multi select parameter

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, multi-select

I have a report with several parameters, all in varying degrees depending on the value of its predecessors.  I’m trying to convert from single selects to multi-selects.  I’ve set the multiselect values for Report Type – see image – and would like to set the default value for the multiselect Jobs Type parameter.  The logic would be:  ‘If Jobs is not selected in Report Type, set ‘*NA*’ as default.  If Jobs is selected, display the list of job types’.  The job type dataset is used as the Available 
Values list.  I have a defaultJobType dataset with the following code:

IF 3 IN (@ReportType)
   SELECT 0 as JobTypeId, 'N/A' as JobTypeDesc

Is there any way to accomplish this goal?

[image: Master Pass Parameters]

[image: Master Pass Report Types]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a DataSet to get "Default JobType" based on report type as per your requirement
like as you said IF 3 IN (@ReportType) SELECT 0 as JobTypeId, 'N/A' as JobTypeDesc

create a SP (stored procedure or query with parameter report type)
as we normally do for  Cascading Parameters ...

once its done then set the default value of Job Type Parameter ,

```
 1. select option "Get value from a query" 
 2. Choose DataSet which created to get Jobtype based on 
 3. set value field JobTypeId
```

you can also say that, there are two data set to populate Job Type one for populating drop down & another for select Default value...